# How to make a .obj Animation

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, obj

I got several .obj files from a face and i want too animate them like keyframing.
However keyframing does not work since the .obj files might differ in small details.
My simplest approach is: make a animation based on showing each .obj just a few miliseconds.
I need to do this with python since this should be automated.
(In the end someone will give me a video, i split the video in frames and get for every frame a .obj file from the face (some Machine-Learning stuff behind there) and then i rebuild the "video" but in 3d.
Is this possible with the python-api from blender ? And when yes, where would i start?

Thanks.